# Sorting array of arrays in Julia

Tags: arrays, sorting, julia

I have array of arrays and I want to sort these arrays in array by their first element. Is something like this possible in Julia?

For example i have

```
a = (Array{Int64, 1})[]
push!(a, [5, 2 , 3])
push!(a, [3, 1 , 4])
```

And i want to sort in in way that the result will be `[[3,1,4], [5,2,3]`. Arrays will be sorted according to their first element.

I need this because heap in Julia is unable to take arrays as element in heap. Any idea???

Comment: Also, the one-liner: `sort(a,by=first)` works (`first` is a useful function to remember).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update for version 1.0**:

```
sort(a)
```

That's it.  Julia version 1.0 defines `<` for arrays to be the lexicographic sorting I describe below, so you don't need to manually specify it anymore.

---

**Previous answer for 0.6**

You can specify a custom `lt` (less than) operator as a [keyword argument to `sort`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/sort/):

```
julia> sort(a, lt=(x,y)->isless(x[1], y[1]))
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [3,1,4]
 [5,2,3]
```

More generally, you can use [`lexless`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6/stdlib/base/#Base.lexless) to robustly sort the arrays in lexicographic order:

```
julia> push!(a, [5, 1, 1])
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [5,2,3]
 [3,1,4]
 [5,1,1]

julia> sort(a, lt=lexless)
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [3,1,4]
 [5,1,1]
 [5,2,3]
```

Comment: Thanks this will do the job. I just want to ask. Are you familiar with heaps in JULIA. Do you know if heap in JULIA can take array as element ? I know python have this opportunity and I want to replicate in it JULIA and this thing with array of arrays is only idea that came to my mind. But I do not like it to much as it's time complexity is worst than for heap.

Comment: Use the optional `ord` argument to specify lexicographic ordering: `Collections.heapify(a, Base.Order.Lexicographic)`.

Comment: Interesting. But is heap order maintained with `Collections.heappush!(v, x[, ord])` also ? And is there possibility to add array to heap with it ? Something like `Collections.heappush!(a,[5,2,3])` ? I tried a lot of variances but nothing worked.

Comment: I was using for example `Collections.heappush!(a, [10, 1 , 4])` to add element  and it did not work but after your suggestions on heapify i tried `Collections.heappush!(a, [10, 1 , 4], Base.Order.Lexicographic)` and it works so thanks a lot. But lexicographic is sorting based on alphabet or how ? Is there possibility to run it with this `lt=(x,y)->isless(x[1], y[1])` ?

Comment: Lexicographic just means that it sorts by the first element, and then if they're equal, it goes to the next.  And it handles varying length arrays (including empty ones), too.  But if you just want to change the `lt` comparison function, you can construct a custom ordering with `Base.Order.ord((x,y)->isless(x[1], y[1]), identity, false)`.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot  :-)